# Rule S1144 "Remove unused private method" c# - VS 2015

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarlint

Methods *Visit(Leaf v)* and *Visit(Composite v)* are marked as unused by SonarLint.
Also SonarQube marks it as unused. But it invoked with dynamic.
Does anybody knows how to fix it? Probably there some configuration?
Entry point is one *Visit(Base root)*, then using dynamic call it will traverse tree.

UPD: Updated example

This is sample:

```
public void Visit(Base root)
{
   Visit((dynamic)root);
}

private void Visit(Composite v )
{
    v.Children.ForEach(el => Visit((dynamic)el));
}

private void Visit(Leaf v)
{
    // do smth
}

class Base
{
} 

class Composite : Base
{
    public IEnumerable<Base> Children { get;}
}

class Leaf : Base
{

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you call `Visit`?

Comment: @dotctor yes, srry entry point was wrong, updated code. This is light sample.

But Visit was also invoked in v.Children.ForEach(el => Visit((dynamic)el));

Comment: @mybirthname Remove sonar - it's not a case or solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a false positive in SonarLint. Currently there's no fix for this. We should probably use the `CandidateSymbols` when we resolve the method reference. I created a ticket for it here: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLVS-1080